# multiple plots in r, a, b, c, d with lines and curves

Tags: r, plot

I have some pretty nice plots that I want to present in a report, but I would like to have multiple plots with one common legend, title and caption. The problem is the lines in the plots. So far I have made a plot and added lines or curves from one or several binomial models. These curves/lines exist in different data.frames, but they can fit in the same plot because they have the same parameters and lengths.

I have tried to make a plot where I add all the lines at the same time as the plot is being created but then only the lines show up and i got a lot of errors.

So when `i` create a plot with lines `i` do like this:

```
plot(Spruce,Leaves,xlab="Spruce",ylab="Leaves>0")

g=glm(Leaves>0~Spruce,family=binomial,data=1)
g2=glm(Leaves>0~Spruce,family=binomial,data=2)

curve(predict(g,data.frame("Spruce"=x),type="resp"),add=TRUE,col="blue")
curve(predict(g2,data.frame("Spruce"=x),type="resp"),add=TRUE,col="red")
```

I cannot upload a picture of the plot, but it's nice.

The problem is that I need to present it with several other plots to explain my point and then I would like to do it as one of several a,b,c,d plots.
I have used

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
```

To have all plots visual at the same time but I would like to name them a,b,c,d and have a common legend, title and mtext.

Any suggestions how to do that?

Comment: Can you post `dput(Spruce)` and `dput(Leaves)`? It will help show you how to do this.

Comment: > dput(Leaves,file="1")
> 0.04097

Comment: > dput(Spruce,file="1")
> 0.04097

Comment: dput(Leaves,file="2") gets the same result-I´m not sure i making this right.

Comment: Leaves is a binomial vector, and what i´ve done is to see how it corresponds to the amount of Spruce in a limited area.

Comment: I have done this for two different datafarmes due to another parameter that could affect the result, and by the commands i´ve used so far i can get regression lines from both dataframes in the same plot.

Comment: Without your data (or some portion of your data, or some simulated data) it is very hard to help, or even really understand what your problem is. The purpose of `dput()` is to allow us to re-create your data structures on our own computers. Run the commands (as written) suggested by @nograpes, and then paste the output into your question (edit your question to include the new stuff).

Comment: Okej i think simulated data could work best in this case

Comment: >dataframe 1 > Spruce>c(8,9,10, 5,7,6,8,9,7)> Leaves>c(1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0)                                             >dataframe1>Spruce>c(10,8,6,5,4,3,4,5,6)> Leaves>c(1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1)